# Formatting with numpy.savetxt from hdf5?

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, hdf5

```
import numpy
import tables

file = tables.openFile( "....hdf5","r")
lon = numpy.array(file.root.lon)
lon.ravel()
lat = numpy.array(file.root.lat)
lat.ravel()
data = numpy.array(file.root.data)

v0= data.shape[0]
v1= data.shape[1]
v2= data.shape[2]
wind_spectrum_flat = data.reshape((v0, v1*v2))

interval_spectrum = numarray.arange(30) + 0.5
speed_mean = numarray.dot(interval_spectrum, wind_spectrum_flat)/days/24.
value = numarray.reshape(speed_mean, (v1, v2) )
value.ravel()
```

print lat.shape,lon.shape,value.shape

(480,640) (480,640) (307200,)

```
output = numpy.column_stack((lon,lat,value))
```

The outputs are like:

```
1.131087052608466621e+02   2.245298999778770010e+01   3.922619047619047450e+001.131096961042312046e+02   2.245299666446372910e+01
```

How can I format them to get three numeric(not scientific) columns in each line? i.e.:

```
11310870  224529 3.922
11310969  224529 4.512
11320485  223643 5.332
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use savetxt fmt keyword as such :

```
numpy.savetxt(out_name,output, fmt="%u %u %.3f")
```

You will output 2 integers and one float with 3 digits before the dot this way.

To ensure that each of your vector has a correct vector shape (1-dimensional array), you can replace in your code the :

```
x = x.flat
```

by :

```
x.ravel()
```

where x can be your lon, lat and data vectors.

Comment: or how to force it to change into a new line every three elements?

Comment: I replaced .flat with .ravel, but i got     fh.write(format % tuple(row) + '\n')
TypeError: float argument required

Comment: You did called ravel() with the parenthesis ?

Comment: I didn't at the first time,but when i changed it to ravel(),i got ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0
...the original lat and lon arrays are (480,640), but the original data array is (30,480,640),coule this be the problem?

Comment: That's the problem. Which part of the data array do you want to save along lon and lat ? You could display it all, but you would need to format your output to have 32 column, right ?

Comment: I modified the code in my question.I calulated the mean value of data array, so the lat, lon and data arrays are (480,640) now.But numpy.column_stack returned  ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0 ..